# Perform data mapping in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have data coming from multiple hotels. These hotels are not using the same naming convention for storing the order information. I have a predefined dataset created in the bigquery(called hotel_order). I
want to map the data coming from different hotels to the single dataset in GCP, so it is easier for me to do comparisons in the bigquery.

If the column name(from hotel1) matches the bigquery dataset columnname, then the bigquery should load the data in the column, if the columnnames (from hotel orders data and dataset in bigquery) don't match, then column in the bigquery should have the null value. How do I do implement this in GCP? Problem of mapping in the GCP?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join tables together, and show a null value when a match doesn't exist, then you can do so using 'left join'.

**Rough example**
`from hotel.orders as main left join hotel_number_one as Hotel_One on main.order_information = Hotel_One.order_information`

Difficult to give a more detailed answer without more details or a working example using dbfiddle.